# Что такое терминал в Unix?

Tags: unix

Что такое терминал в Unix? И чем он отличается от той же мышки, например, или принтера.
Определение в стиле: терминал — это точка входа пользователя в систему, обладающая способностью передавать текстовую информацию - не подходит. Можете, пожалуйста, более подробно объяснить что это.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компьютерный_терминал

Comment: Неоднозначный вопрос, не могу для себя решить, по теме ли (понятен ли, полезен ли) он или нет (скорее нет). Почему бы сначала сюда не сходить ["Что такое терминал в Unix?"](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=Что%20такое%20терминал%20в%20Unix%3F&clid=1955455&win=412&&lr=213)? Чего именно не хватило в открытых источниках?

Comment: Это устройство, для которого функция [isatty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) возвращает 1